# Error with Remote Pagination in Tabulator 5.0

Tags: javascript, ajax, pagination, tabulator

My tabulator 5.0 table works fine. But when I attempt to use remote pagination it no longer works at all.

```
var table = new Tabulator("#account-tran-detail-table", {
    pagination:true,
    paginationMode:"remote", //if this line is commented out then it works fine without pagination
    paginationSize: 12,
    dataSendParams:{
        page: "page",
        size: "page_size",
    },
    dataReceiveParams:{
        last_page:"total_pages",
    } ,
    ajaxResponse:function(url, params, response){
        return response.results; // return the array of table items
    },
});

table.on("tableBuilt", function(){
    table.setColumns(columns);
});

function generateReport () {
    table.clearData();
    var columns = [
            {title:"id", field:"id", headerFilter:false, visible:false, download:true},
            {title:"name", field:"name", headerFilter:false, visible:false, download:true},
        ];

    var gender = "m";
    var url = "/api/v1/myendpointname/";
    var append_params = "?gender=" + gender;

    $("#tableBuilt").destroy;
    table.setData(url + append_params);
};
```

The response looks like this:

```
{
    "count": 10,
    "total_pages": 3,
    "next": "http://localhost:8000/myendpointname/?gender=m&page=2&size=3
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "gender": "m",
            "name": "abc",
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "gender": "m",
            "name": "def",
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "gender": "m",
            "name": "ghi",
        },
    ]
}
```

You can see where I'm asking tabulator to read `total_pages` instead of the default `last_page` by using `dataReceiveParams`. And you can also see where I'm asking tabulator to send `page_size` instead of the default `size` by using `dataSendParams` to generate the request.

I get two warnings . . .

```
Remote Pagination Error - Server response missing 'undefined' property Page.js:707:11
Remote Pagination Error - Server response missing 'undefined' property Page.js:754:11
```

Followed by an error.

```
Data Loading Error - Unable to process data due to invalid data type 
Expecting: array 
Received: undefined
Data: undefined
```

The code referenced by the warnings:

```
707: console.warn("Remote Pagination Error - Server response missing '" + this.dataReceivedNames.last_page + "' property");
754: console.warn("Remote Pagination Error - Server response missing '" + this.dataReceivedNames.data + "' property");
```

So it seems to me that tabulator isn't "seeing" the `total_pages` portion of the response. Why is it not using `defaultReceiveParams`? Could it be because of my `ajaxResponse` function returns `response.results` and strips the rest of the response away?

(Same behavior for Chrome and Firefox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ajaxResponse` to return data and last_page as

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-70091378-4izoz?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Thank you. I've come to believe there is a bug in Tabulator.  Your workaround helped me to move forward.